# Wordpress - List all pages that have children but show children than for the current page

Tags: wordpress

The tree of my pages :

```
- Teeshirts
    * Long
    * Big
    * Short
- Sweat
    * Hot
    * Cold
- Pants
- Skirts
```

**On the active page** (for example Teeshirts) , I want to display all parent pages and children of the current page :

```
- Teeshirts (ACTIVE PAGE)
    * Long
    * Big
    * Short
- Sweat
- Pants
- Skirts
```

The children pages of sweat is not display.

Can you help me ?

Thank youuuu

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) {
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);?>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->post_parent) ?>"><?php echo $parent_title;?></a></li>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Read also,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_list_pages-parent-and-children-pages

Comment: Thanks you but it's not work. I already try this... I want to hide child pages of NO current page...